# Tensor product decomposition of commuting representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras

If $\mathscr{X}$ is a Hilbert space, we denote by $\mathrm{GL}(\mathscr{X})$ the group of all bounded operators on $\mathscr{X}$ with bounded inverses. Let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be the free group on two generators. Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\xi:\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathscr{X})$ be a linear representation. Let also $\zeta:\mathbb{F}_2 \to \mathrm{U}(\mathscr{X})$ be a unitary representation which commutes with $\xi$. Consider the following pair of statements.

(1) There exist Hilbert spaces $\mathscr{Y}$ and $\mathscr{Z}$, a linear representation $\overline{\xi}:\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathscr{Y})$, a unitary representation $\overline{\zeta}:\mathbb{F}_2 \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathscr{Z})$ and a unitary operator $u:\mathscr{X} \to \mathscr{Y} \otimes \mathscr{Z}$ such that $u(\xi \times \zeta)u^{-1} = \overline{\xi} \otimes \overline{\zeta}$.

(2) $\xi$ is unitary.

It is standard that (2) implies (1), in fact with $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ replaced by any finite group. Is it the case that (1) implies (2)?

Comment: What does it mean for two representations to commute?  Just that each operator $\xi(g)$ commutes with each (i.e., the non-trivial) operator $\zeta(h)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Could you sketch why (1) implies (2).  Is it an "averaging" argument (making use of the fact we have a finite group?)  And, I'm being very slow, but what exactly is $SL(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: There was an error on my part in the original post - I forgot to add the subscript 2 in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. Thus $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is the group of all $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and determinant $1$.

Comment: The fact that (2) implies (1) follows from the proof of Lemma 11.3.11 in MR1468230.

Comment: @burtonpeterj  According to my MathSciNet access, that's Kadison+Ringrose.  And Lemma 11.3.11 says that a finite dimensional $C^*$-algebra is nuclear.  How does the result follow from that?